# Apply Drupal Patch using composer.json file

Tags: json, drupal, composer-php, patch

How to apply a patch for Drupal modules files through a `composer.json` file?

Basically, I have installed slick module and customised code and created a patch file using "git diff" command.  Slick module file path is `modules/contrib/slick/` directory. Below is the code that i have written in the composser.json file.

```
"require": {
        "drupal/slick": "^2.7",
}

----------------------------------

"patches": {
  "drupal/slick": {
  "Slick custom changes": "patches/slick/slick.patch"
},
```

But when running composer install, it just removes this slick package from "modules/contrib/slick, but does not reinstall or add the patch.

If i remove "Slick custom changes": "patches/slick/slick.patch" from composer.json and execute composer install cmd then it install slick module.

How to avoid removing this package and applying the patch?

Comment: That JSON you put into your composer json, it is unclear in your question where _inside_ the file you put it. As it stands - even as an excerpt - this remains undefined. Therefore it likely looks like the correct approach of composer to remove it as it is likely not part of the Compser project configuration. First of all you can only configure as outlined in the schema: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md - Please [edit] your question accordingly and add the clarifying information. And OOTB Composer has no feature to apply patches. My recommendation is to use a build manager for that.